# How to create a graph visualisation of a relational database in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, gremlin

I have some normalized Master Data in PostgreSQL.

I want a graph visualization layer in Neo4j without migrating any Data to Neo4j. Kind of like a view. Lazy fetching of data at runtime.

Neo4j will not commit any changes and only meant for viewing.

Can Neo4j use something like a PostgreSQL JDBC connector and provide a visualization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could with `apoc.load.jdbc` and virtual nodes/relationships created from the data. 
But it would be a bit involved as you need to load all tables and then connect them.

With the Neo4j-ETL tool you can do a quick (few min) one-time import to visualize.
https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-etl-1-2-0-release-whats-new-and-demo/

Esp. if you don't just visualize but also query you need to transfer the data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ETL tool, from Neo4j.

You need to ask for an activation key via email at devrel@neo4j.com